# functions are not being called or are not running

Tags: javascript, function

I have been working on this for a week now and cannot figure out for the life of me what I have missed or if I have put something somewhere that it is not supposed to be. the code was working fine until I began making changes to the confirmSubmit() function and now it seems like nothing is working properly other than displaying the page. I had my teacher look at it too and he said that he couldn't find out either. I just don't know anymore maybe one of you all can help me solve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="AS400.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Registration</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    // This JavaScript removes default values form field
       function doClear(theText) {
     if (theText.value == theText.defaultValue) {
         theText.value = ""
     }
 }

// This JavaScript allows characters except numbers
 function AcceptLetters(objtextbox)
{
var exp = /[^\D]/g;
objtextbox.value = objtextbox.value.replace(exp,'');
}

// This JavaScript allows numbers only
 function AcceptDigits(objtextbox)
{
var exp = /[^\d]/g;
objtextbox.value = objtextbox.value.replace(exp,'');
}

//This JavaScript confirms everything is filled out
function confirmSubmit()
{
var submitForm = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?");
var Special offers = false;
var offers = false;



if (document.forms[0].name.value=="Name" || document.forms[0].name.value == "") {
     window.alert("Please input your name.");
    return false;}

 if (document.forms[0].email.value == "E-Mail Address" || document.forms[0].email.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please input your email.");
    return false;}

    if (document.forms[0].password1.value == "" || document.forms[0].password2.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please input your password twice.");
    retrun false;}

if (document.forms[0].SQ.value == "" || document.forms[0].SQ.value == "none") {
    window.alert("Please choose a security question.");
    return false;}

if (document.forms[0].sq_answer.value == "Question Answer"|| document.forms[0].sq_answer.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please input a sequrity question answer.");
    return false;}

    for (var i = 0; i <= 1; ++i) {

    if (document.forms[0].SpecialOffers[i].checked ==  true) {
        Special offers = true;
        break;}
    }

    if (Special offers == false) {
        window.alert("You must select yes or no to special offers.");
        return false;
    }


    for (var k = 0; k <= 3; k++) {
    if (document.forms[0].Offers[k].checked == true) {
        offers = true;
        break;}

    }
    if (offers == false) {
        window.alert("You must choose one offer.");
        return false;}

else
 return true;
 }

/* ]] */
</script>
</head>

<body>


<form  action="FormProcessor.html"  method = "get" enctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return confirmSubmit()">
<table  width="50%">
<tr><th colspan="2"><h1>Registration Page</h1></th></tr>

<tr><th colspan="2"><h2>Personal Information<h2></th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2">(Fields with asterisks are mandatory)</th></tr>
<tr><td>* Name: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="Name" maxlength="20"  onFocus="doClear(this)" onkeyup="AcceptLetters(this)" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>* E-Mail:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" value="E-mail Address" onFocus="doClear(this)" /> </td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>Security Information</h3></th></tr>
<tr><td>* Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>* Confirm Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>* Security Question:</td>
<td><select id="selection" name="SQ">
<option value="none">Please Choose One</option>
<option value="color">What is your favorite color?</option>
<option value="name">What is your Mother's maiden name?</option>
<option value="pet">What is your pets name?</option>
<option value="school">What high school did you graduate from?</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Answer:</td><td><input type="text" name="sq_answer"  value="Question Answer" onFocus="doClear(this)" /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2"><h4>* Preferences</h4></th></tr>

<tr><th colspan="2">Would you like any special offers sent to your E-mail address?</th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2">Yes<input type="radio" name="SpecialOffers" value="Yes"/>No<input type="radio" name="SpecialOffers"  value="No" /></th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2"><h5>Interests</h5></th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="Offers" value="check"/>Entertainment</th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="Offers" value="check"/>Shopping</th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="Offers" value="check"/>Business</th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="Offers" value="check"/>Exercise</th></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>


<tr><th colspan="2"><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/><input id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset"/></th></tr>
</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code with Firebug or Chrome dev tools? If your page isn't displaying content or working properly, chances are there's an error somewhere in your script, and debugging it will reveal the culprit. I get plenty of console errors in  Chrome trying to use your page.

Comment: it is displaying content properly. It is not using the functions though.

Comment: This is not what we do here.  We don't take whole pieces of non-working code with no information about what you've done to debug it and magically solve all your problems.  That's not how StackOverflow works.  If you are working on troubleshooting it and and you have a specific question that you can provide detailed information on, then you might get some help with that.  The first place to start would be to see what errors are reported in the debug console and go from there.

Comment: On a side note, if your teacher isn't (a) teaching you how to use the debugging tools, and (b) was unable to help you track down these syntax errors, I recommend switching teachers.

Comment: i wasn't asking you to fix my code for me just to tell me if you saw something that was screaming to you that it was wrong like Arvind did.

Comment: @Chris he is teaching just not the debugger I didn't even know that there was a debugger until I found it on my own. The teacher isn't bad he is just overwhelmed by 2 teachers being out and him having to pick up the workload plus still do his own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few syntax errors:

`Special offers` variable can't have spaces in it.

Keyword is not `retrun` its `return`.

Comment: Please help teach the OP how to see these errors for themselves rather than use us as syntax checkers.

Comment: I fixed the syntactical errors and it is still doing the same thing where it is still submitting the form with out the error checking being done. Also when I click on the boxes the box is supposed to be cleared of default text but that is not being done either

Comment: yeah I caught that return being wrong and fixed the syntax error and got it all working I really appreciate the help.